# Addition of aqueous KOH to 3-bromobut-1-ene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

On addition of aq $\ce{KOH}$ to 3-bromobut-1-ene, substitution reaction should take place via $S_N1$ mechanism but in this an allylic carbocation forms which could rearrange.

In that case which should be the major product?

But-3-en-2-ol or but-3-en-1-ol, because in the first case the carbocation would be stable because of being secondary but the double bond would have less number of hyperconjugated structures and will be less stable whereas in the latter case, the carbocation would be less stable because it would be primary but the double bond would be much more stable because of 5 $\alpha$ hydrogen available

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion But-3-en-2-ol will be be the major product if the reaction is favored by Sn1 (due to stable carbocation )

Nevertheless, the product in which the OH group is on the primary atom is minor.